# Material UI cannot customize DatePicker in v5.0?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using the latest v5.0 version, and based the [docs](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/#typescript), I'm trying to customize the `DatePicker` with `createTheme`, but style does not seems to be overriden (functionality works fine).

Customizing button works fine, but it does nothing for `DatePickers`?

Theme:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: "yellow", // <- this works fine
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    },
    MuiStaticDatePicker: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: "yellow", // <- it does nothing ???
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    },
    MuiDatePicker: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: "yellow", // <- does nothing too ???
          color: "green"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Component:

```
function App() {
  const [value1, setValue1] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(dayjs(new Date()));
  const [value2, setValue2] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(dayjs(new Date()));

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button>click</Button>

      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <DatePicker
          value={value1}
          onChange={(newValue) => setValue1(newValue)}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />

        <StaticDatePicker
          value={value2}
          displayStaticWrapperAs="desktop"
          onChange={(newValue) => setValue2(newValue)}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

There are many similar questions like this, but they're all from previous versions. So what's the correct way of doing so in v5.0?

Please take a look at [minimal sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-boyd-tx7rft?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: Use the browser developer tools to look at the different layers of elements to see which classes you need to customize. MuiCalendarPicker and MuiPickersDay are two of the main ones: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-mirzakhani-z7h60g?file=/src/App.tsx:919-932

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material UI DatePicker is collection of components and not a single component. You need to target individual components inside datepicker. You can inspect the DatePicker in developer tools then check inside `class` what component name it is showing then you can use that component name to overwrite style using theme. below I have provided some sample components to test, You can extend this as per your need.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCalendarPicker: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: "yellow",
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    },
    MuiDayPicker: {
      styleOverrides: {
        header: {
          backgroundColor: "green",
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    },
    MuiPickersDay: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: "brown",
          color: "red"
        },
        today: {
          backgroundColor: "orange",
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    },
  }
});
```